Why was this question on the difference between Starlink Roam and Starlink Boats closed?
I see that What is the difference between Starlink Roam and Starlink Boats? got closed.  Both Starlink Roam and Starlink Boats are designed to be used when traveling, and Internet access is a key concern when traveling (hence internet). So why was the question closed?
There is a single comment:

I’m voting to close this question because it is about starlink tos, not travel. littleadv Commented 7 hours ago

However, asking about ToS doesn't imply it's off-topic. E.g., we don't close questions because the answers are in some airlines and car rental ToS:

Can I travel with Ryanair with a DSLR special bag as second hand luggage?
In US rental car terms and conditions, what exactly is a "regularly maintained road?"


Airlines and car rental companies are directly travel related.  An internet company is not.

@Midavalo Starlink Roam and Starlink Boats are directly travel related. It's made for people traveling.

The question doesn't currently seem to be closed.

@MadHatter reopened

Right, yes, I'd worked that out.  What I'm wondering is whether you still want this question answered, and if so, how?

@MadHatter yes, to reduce the likelihood the same mistake is made. I wrote one

But the comment trail (and mod-visible history) on the original question will already do that.  I’m voting to close this question because it's no longer applicable.

@MadHatter future questions may benefit from it

@MadHatter comments are temporary and meta is the proper place to discuss close reasons.

I don't dispute that for a moment.  My question is merely whether it makes sense to spend time discussing the closure of a question which isn't closed.  I think it isn't; you think it is.  Fair enough.  We'll let the community judge!

The question was eventually reopened: Starlink Roam and Starlink Boats were ubderstanbly deemed about traveling, since they are designed for travelers.
